# Keep maximum date every 30 days starting from a beginning date

Tags: sql, vertica

I am trying to keep the max date every 30 days based on a starting date. For simplicity's sake, I tested it on one ID, but the actual data contains many IDs.

My data looks something like this:

```
ID     date
A      15JAN2016
A      11MAR2016
A      13MAY2016
A      25MAY2016
A      26MAY2016
A      08JUN2016
A      09JUN2016
A      10JUN2016
```

The end table should look like this:

```
ID      Max_srv_dt_1    Max_srv_dt_2   Max_srv_dt_3  Max_srv_dt_4
A       15Jan2016       11Mar2016      13May2016     10JUN2016
```

My code:

```
 SELECT c1.ID, 
        MIN_SRV_DT_1, 
        Max_SRV_DT_2, 
        Max(C2.date) OVER (PARTITION BY c2.ID ORDER BY C2.date+30) Max_SRV_DT_3
 FROM
    (SELECT c1.ID, MIN_SRV_DT_1, max(C2.date) OVER (PARTITION BY c2.ID ORDER BY C2.date+30) Max_SRV_DT_2
       FROM 
          (SELECT c1.ID, MIN(C1.date) MIN_SRV_DT_1
           FROM max_ep_test C1
           GROUP BY c1.ID) C1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN max_ep_test C2  
         ON c1.ID = c2.ID
        AND C2.date < C1.MIN_SRV_DT_1 + 30
      ) C1
      LEFT OUTER JOIN max_ep_test C2
        ON c1.ID = c2.ID
       AND C2.date > max_srv_dt_2 + 30
```

I get something like the following, and can't figure out how to change the parameters to actually take the correct dates:

```
ID   min_srv_dt_1   max_srv_dt_2   max_srv_dt_3
A    15JAN2016      15JAN2016      11MAR2016
A    15JAN2016      15JAN2016      13MAR2016
A    15JAN2016      15JAN2016      13MAY2016
A    15JAN2016      15JAN2016      25MAY2016
A    15JAN2016      15JAN2016      26MARY016
A    15JAN2016      15JAN2016      08JUN2016
A    15JAN2016      15JAN2016      09JUN2016
A    15JAN2016      15JAN2016      10JUN2016
```

Comment: How many day back you need? only 90 or more? or maybe all?

Comment: All 30 day periods starting from 15Jan2016 for the whole year, although I can extend the code if the first few dates are correct (not sure if there's a better way to do this than many left outer joins).

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you can do it with window framing, read [here](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AnalyzingData/WindowsWithALogicalOffsetRANGE.htm%3FTocPath%3DAnalyzing%2520Data%7CUsing%2520SQL%2520Analytics%7CThe%2520Window%2520OVER()%2520Clause%7CWindow%2520Framing%7C_____2) (last example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the difference between the any date and the earliest date using `datediff()`.  The rest is just aggregation:

```
select id, max(date)
from (select et.*,
             datediff('day', min(date) over (partition by id), date) as datediff_day
      from max_ep_test et
     ) et
group by floor(datediff_day / 30);
```

Comment: OP need max date for 30 day period. Also need that field so can do Pivot after that aggregation. [**Pivot in Vertica**](https://forum.vertica.com/discussion/211469/are-there-sql-commands-to-pivot-data)

Comment: I get an ERROR: Operator does not exist: int - date